# How to update NFT metadata inserted to candy machine?

Tags: nft, metadata, mint, candymachine

I've created candy machine and already inserted 100 items.
now I need to update metadata of 20 items.
I tried with metaplex.nfts().update() but it requires transaction dialog.
what I want to know is need 20 transaction dialog for change 20 items metadata?
or is there another way to solve this?
please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I've found an solution.

you can use metaplex.nfts().update() to update the nft metadata.
however you have to set the mutable flag to true to change metadata after minted.